# Get month and date from React moment

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have a date on `Wed Dec 25 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530`. I want to format into `25 Dec`
How can I do that?

```
const date= currentItem.date;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert it into moment

```
let date_moment=moment(currentItem.date,"ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ")
```

Then convert it to required format

```
let req_format=date_moment.format("DD MMM")
```

Note: if your timeformat is 12 hour use hh.   for other datetime format and timezone format check moment documentation :) [Moment Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Comment: It can be installed with npm or used directly by adding moment.js from their website to your project.

Comment: Its getting an invalid date.

Comment: console.log(Date);  output-2019-12-25T00:00:00.000Z       cconst formattedTargetDate=targetDate.format("DD MMM");       output- Invalid date

Comment: Sorry didn;t noticed GMT .   try .   ` date_moment=moment("Wed Dec 25 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530")

Answer (score 1):

This snippet of code will get exactly what you want from any date entered as variable name `date` to `dateIn`.

```
var dateIn = moment(date, 'YYYY/MM/DD');

var month = dateIn.format('M');
var day = dateIn.format('D');

console.log(day + " " + month);
```

Comment: Yes, it gets a part of a date, in my answer the format is incorrect for what you are trying to input. If you replace `YYYY/MM/DD` with the String in the same parameter from @prasid444 's answer, then it will provide the correct result

Comment: Cool seems like youve fixed your problem, please close the thread by marking a correct answer